# Fragment blank after popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

<s>I have this Activity in which I replace the main fragment with a preference fragment. When I click back after looking at the preferences, I get a blank (white) area where my fragment should be. If I rotate the screen then it works just fine. Everything in my fragment appears to be ok except for it is blank. Here are my methods:</s>

The onCreate method of the activity.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          .....
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

          getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(MAIN_CONTAINER, new MainFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

The starting of the preferences fragment:

```
public void startPreferencesFragment() {
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        MyPreferencesFragment mPrefsFragment = new MyPreferencesFragment();
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(MAIN_CONTAINER, mPrefsFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

The onBackPressed of my activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();

            return;

        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: If I open preferences and then rotate and then press back, it all works fine.

Also I should mention that removing the onBackPressed method does not fix the issue, it just exits the app.

EDIT: Turned out to not be a problem with the fragment back stack at all. Basically my fragment has a recyclerview and that is all it has. The instance of the adapter I was setting on the recyclerview was being kept while the recyclerview itself was new when the fragment was brought back from the back stack and I was checking whether the adapter was null when setting it.

Comment: why did you override `onBackPressed`? The super class takes already care of popup transaction in the backstack

Comment: That is what I keep hearing but if I don't do that then the app just exits.

Answer (score 3):

You are already adding the transaction to the backstack, there is not need to override `onBackPressed()`; the framework will pop the `Fragment` out of the stack automatically when the back button is pressed. I am pretty sure that you are "double" popping the backstack.

Comment: I've tried it without that and then the app just exits. I should also have mentioned that if I open the settings screen then rotate, the back button works fine.

Comment: If I do that on the exact code above which means `super.onBackPressed()` never gets called, then nothing happens at all.

Comment: Well it isn't the right answer because it does not fix the problem and personally I have found that once there is an answer, specially one with an up vote, most people tend to ignore the question. I will remove the down vote once I'm allowed to do so as apparently you can't change votes frequently.

Comment: What happens if you move `addToBackStack()` after you call `replace()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71914/discussion-between-emmanuel-and-mntgoat).

Comment: That is how I had it before. Same behavior. Also I should point out that if I step my code I can see the right fragment having `onCreateView` called when I hit back. I also have buttons on the toolbar that interact with it and they work fine except for nothing shows up. Those buttons call `findFragmentById` to get the fragment and it returns the right fragment.